# Smith-Volterra-Cantor set remove "m"th interval

Tags: measure-theory

Is it possible to determine the measure of the Cantor set by removing the middle "m"th interval (m=1,2,3,4,...) from [0,1]?

For example, removing middle 3rd from [0,1] gives measure 0; removing middle 4th from [0,1] gives measure 1/2. Is there a general formula for finding the measure of the SVC set as a result of removing any "m"th interval?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the sum of intervals is:
$$
q+2q^2+4q^3+\dots=q\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2q)^n=\frac{q}{1-{2q}}.
$$
For $q=\frac13$ it is 1, and for $q=\frac14$ it is $\frac12$.